# How can I align an ID in a POP-UP Window with VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database in Excel 2010 listing different measuring equipment.
Each piece has an ID and some other stuff is known.

```
Each entry line looks like this:
ID    …     …   Need for a pop-up?
1     …     …         NO
2     …     …         YES
3     …     …         NO
4     …     …         NO
```

and so on.

Out of information like availability or functionality, I have created a formula that sums up these information and gives the answer "YES" or "NO" to the question:"Need for a pop-up warning?"
So whenever someone wants to lend a piece of equipment that might not work/be available, the user should be warned with a pop-up saying something like: "Warning for: Device with ID 111. This gauge might be defect/not available."

I already have some code that will give me a pop-up message every time the question:"Need for a pop-up" is answered with "YES" but I fail to align the ID of the affected piece in the text of the pop-up.

```
Sub POP_UP_if_defect()

    'In Cells N6:N500 are the answers "YES" or "NO" listed

    For Each Cell In Sheets ("Sheet X").Range("N6:N500")
        If Cell.Value = "YES" Then
            MsgBox "Warning: This device might be defect/not available!"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `cell` contains "YES", you have to get the id from Column "A" of that row. Try something like this:

```
With Sheets("Sheet X")
    For Each cell In .Range("N6:N500")
        If cell.Value = "YES" Then
            Dim id
            id = .Cells(cell.row, 1)
            MsgBox "Warning: device " & id & " might be defect/not available!"
        End If
    Next cell
End With
```